# Firefox разрывает таблицу при печати

Tags: html, css, firefox, печать

У меня есть страница, которую пользователь может распечатывать.

На этой странице есть таблица.

Печать в **Chrome** отображается верно, а в **Firefox** таблица разрезается на несколько страниц, на одной - шапка таблицы, на другой - содержимое таблицы.

---

#### Пример в Chrome

[image: Печать таблицы в Chrome]

---

#### Пример в Firefox

[image: Некорректная печать таблицы в Firefox]

Может кто-то сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Возможно сказывается невалидная вёрстка? Проверьте валидатором, что он скажет ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в стиле добавить свойство `page-break-inside: avoid;`
Подробнее [здесь.](http://htmlbook.ru/css/page-break-inside)
А [здесь](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-page-break) можно посмотреть поддерживаемые версии браузеров.

Comment: По указанной ссылке отмечено, что в Firefox нет поддержки этого свойства.

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-page-break)